# how instructions are fetched in cortex M processors

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, cortex-m

As far as I understand, Cortex M0/M3 processors have only one memory space that holds instructions and data and that the access is only through the memory bus interface. Thus, if I understand correctly, every clock cycle the processor must read a new instruction to enter the pipeline, but that means that the bus will always be busy reading instructions so how data can be read simultaneously (for load word/store word instructions for example)?
Additionally, what is the latency of reading an instruction from the memory? since if it is not a single cycle, then the processor must constantly halt itself until the next instruction is fetched, so how it is handled?

Thanks

Comment: every clock cycle the pipe wants a new instruction vs needs a new instruction.  as with any pipelined processor the processor stalls because we cant feed it, mcus have less "stuff" around them than a bigger sized one so are expected to stall a lot more.

Comment: One memory space does not imply one bus and thus bus contention.  And one "bus" in ARMs world is not one bus...Before it leaves the ARM IP it ends up as multiple busses with multiple busses within each bus.  It then ends up in the hands of the chip vendor as to how they keep separate or sometimes merge the busses in their product.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is how it happens, the processor stalls a lot, this goes on with big processors as well as small, difficult at best to feed a pipelined processor (although some of these pipes are shallow on cortex-ms, but pipelined nevertheless).

Many of the parts I have used and I have touched most of the vendors, the flash is at half clock speed of the core, so even at zero wait states you can only get an instruction every other clock (on average naturally with overhead rolled in) if fetching a halfword at a time, if fetching a word at a time which many of the cores offer then that is ideally two instructions per two clocks or one per.  thumb2 of course you take the hit.  ST definitely has a prefetcher/cacher thing with a fancy marketing name that does a pretty good job.  Others may offer that as well or just rely on what arm offers which varies.

The different cortex-ms have different mixtures of busses.  I hate the von-Neumann/Harvard references as there is little practical use for an actual Harvard architecture, thus the "modified" adjective which means they can do anything and try to attract folks taught in school that Harvard means performance.  The busses can have multiple transactions in flight and there are a different number of busses as is somewhat obvious when you go in and release clocks for a peripheral, apb1 clock control ahb2 clock control, etc.  Peripherals, flash, etc.  But we can run code from sram, so it's not Harvard.  Forget Harvard and von-Neumann terms and just focus on the actual implementation.

The bus documentation is as readily available as the core documentation.  If you buy the right fpga board you can request a free eval of a core which you can then get an up close and personal view as to how it really works.

End of the day there is some parallelism, but on many chips the flash is half speed so if you are not fetching two per or have some other solution you are barely making it and stalling often if you have other same bus accesses.  Likewise on many of these chips the peripherals can't run as fast as the core, so that alone incurs a stall, but even if the peripheral runs on the same clock doesn't mean it turns around a csr or data access as fast as sram, so you incur a stall there too.

There is no reason to assume you will get one instruction per clock performance out of these parts any more than a full sized arm or x86 or other.

While there are some important details that are not documented and only seen when you get the core there is documentation on each core and bus to get a rough idea if how to tune your code to perform better or tune your expectations of how it will really perform.  I know I have demonstrated this here and elsewhere, it is pretty easy even with an ST to see a performance difference between flash and sram and see that it takes more clocks than instructions to perform a benchmark.

Your question is too broad in a few ways. The cortex-m0 and m3 are quite different, one was the first one out and dripping with features, the other was tuned for size and has just less stuff in general not meant to necessarily compete in this way.  Then how long is the latency, etc, that is strictly chip company and family within the chip company so that questions extremely broad all the cortex-m products out there, dozens of different answers to that question.  ARM makes cores not chips, the chip vendors make chips and buy IP from various places and make some of their own, some small part of that chip might be some IP they buy from a processor vendor.

Comment: Interesting point: I have historically corrected the spelling of "busses" as my spell-checker does not like it. However, I learned today that [it used to be considered to be correct](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/plural-of-bus). In the interests of compromise, I will try to remember to leave this one be.

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is known as the "von Neumann bottleneck", and in machines with a pure von Neumann architecture with shared data and program memory, accesses are usually interleaved.  However you might like to check out the "modified Harvard architecture", because that's basically what is in use here.  The backing store is shared like in a von Neumann machine, but the instruction and data fetch paths are separate like in a Harvard machine and crucially they have separate caches.  So if an instruction or data fetch results in a cache hit, a memory fetch doesn't takes place and there is no bottleneck.

The second part of your question doesn't make a great deal of sense I'm afraid, because it is meaningless to talk about instruction fetch times in terms of instruction cycles.  By definition, if an instruction fetch is delayed for some reason, the execution of that instruction (and subsequent instructions) must be delayed.  Typically this is done by inserting NOPs into the pipeline until the next instruction is ready (known as "bubbling" the pipeline).

Comment: It's certainly meaningful to talk about instruction fetch latency.  That's part of branch latency: cycles until useful instruction bytes arrive after a branch changes PC.  (Without branch prediction, there's AFAIK no attempt to hide that latency in a simple pipeline like Cortex-M3.  That's what makes taken branches cost extra cycles.)

Comment: its not really harvard though which is obvious, they can have multiple transactions and transaction types going on at the same time on the same bus and I think they want to use the harvard name on that.  It is a bus bottleneck independent of labels people want to use.  And for a number of these cortex-m implementations the flash is at half the clock speed of the cpu so the cpu spends a lot of time waiting.  not to mention as documented the fetches are either halfword or word and on some cores determined at compile time (of the core).

Comment: st has a cache thing with a fancy name that helps that approach zero wait state, bigger numbered (m4, m7) have optional i caches to help even if the chip vendor doesnt.  But it is not like big brother/sister full sized arms where 4, 8, or more instructions are fetched in one transaction.

Comment: the amba/axi/ahb/apb documents are available and the block diagrams show what goes where, its not so much harvard (harvard is really an academic notion, you cant have a practical product that is truly harvard with no connection between I and D), the cortex-ms have multiple busses and perpherals are hung off of some and ram and flash on others.  Not harvard, just multiple busses, same as we have with a von Neumann implementation.

Comment: @PeterCordes Agreed, it's meaningful to talk about instruction fetch latency of course.  But the OP appeared to be getting tangled up by trying to think of latency in terms of a number of _instructions_ rather than a number of clock cycles, and that's what I was suggesting was meaningless.

Comment: @old_timer Whether you like the terminology or not, "modified Harvard" is a very common moniker for the "separate fetch mechanisms, probably separate caches, one memory space" approach that's almost ubiquitous these days.

Comment: @cooperised: The question doesn't use the term "instruction cycles".  I think the question makes sense if you interpret every use of "cycles" as "clock cycles", and I don't see an implication from context that conflicts with that.  The only possibly-invalid assumption is that instruction fetch happens in terms of single instructions, instead of aligned words.  On machines with a 32-bit bus, fetch can pull two thumb instructions in one cycle.

Comment: But latency from request to receipt of data is still a thing unless there's a prefetch buffer. (Which there is, for obvious reasons, to bottleneck on fetch bandwidth, not latency, in non-branching code, and leave cycles free for data access without stalling as much, in case code is running from the same physical memory as the load or store.)

Comment: @cooperised modified harvard is indistinguishable from modified von Neumann, but marketing is only ever going to pick one term because of the perceived notion of one term over the other based purely on a few minutes in a classroom one day rather than the realities of processor design and chip implementation.  The classroom barely covers the basics on this and pretty much all other processor related topics (pipes, caches, prefetching, etc).  And this leads to questions like this and companies that instead of choose to educate and be accurate rather try to draw in customers by mangling terms.

Comment: The biggest problem is that these terms are mentioned at all every for any reason outside a classroom, it causes problems not solutions.  This question and the realities of it have to do with pipelines and address space and again limitations of textbooks and classrooms.  General purpose processors cant keep the pipe fed, even with all the tricks, it stalls simply because it cant get instructions in time.  Period, end of story, full sized or mcu sized.  Been that way since pipelined cores came to be.

Comment: Specialty cores, not sold as IP, sure, been there seen that you can keep that pipe fed (so long as there are no peripheral accesses, and there are ways to work through that).  it has nothing to do with von Neumann it has to do with being a pipelined architecture and chip vendor choices with the cores they create and or purchase and how they implement their chip design.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fair enough - that's not how I read the question but I understand your interpretation of it.

Answer (score 0):

re: part 2: Instruction fetch can be pipelined to hide some / all of the fetch latency.  Cortex-M3 has a prefetch unit with a 3-word FIFO.
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0337/e/introduction/prefetch-unit  (This can hold up to six 16-bit Thumb instructions.)

This buffer can also supply instructions while data load/store is happening, in a config where those compete with each other (not Harvard split bus, and without a data or instruction cache).

This prefetch is of course *speculative*; discarded on branches.  (It's simple and small enough not to be worth doing branch *prediction* to try to fetch from the right place before decode even knows the upcoming instruction stream contains a branch.)